# Open a specific window when written "npm start"

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I was wondering is there a way to, when written "npm start", for the browser not to open "localhost:3000", but something like this: "localhost:3000/param=1"? And I don't want this to be only on my PC. I want when someone else installs my react app they too open a window with the parameters. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you used `create-react-app`?

Comment: Yes I did use it.

Comment: Are you using react-router or something similar?  Will a redirect when the app is opened work for you?

Comment: Its a normal react app, all I want is when I write "npm start" to start my app, to be redirected to a different link, which has some parameters

Comment: Understood, but there's really no such thing as a "normal" react app.  Everyone has different needs and does things differently.  There are many ways of doing a redirect.  Giving us more details as to how exactly you are using React and its many components will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use React Router and just return this redirect from the start page:

```
<Redirect to="/param=1/" />
```

[React Router Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try specifying the homepage in your package.json?

```
  "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was actually very simple. All I needed was to write a JavaScript file that would redirect the user to the link "localhost:3000/?param=1" when they were on that link, but with no parameters. Here is the javascript code:

```
  // This is the variable where the url params are stored
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  console.log(queryString);
  // This will catch the letters in the url "?param=1" because 9 is excluded
  var firstFewChars = queryString.substring(0,9);
  // If there is no characters after the "/" Aka if there is only "localhost:3000" then
  // it will redirect the user to the url "localhost:3000/?param=-1"
  if(firstFewChars == "") {
    window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/?param=-1");
  }
```